# Gravity Forms -> Gravity Flow: Change Field Data When Workflow is Cancelled

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Hello Amazing Developers,

**What I am Using**

- WordPress Multisite Version 5.8.1
- Gravity Forms Version 2.5.10
- Gravity Flow Version 2.7.4

**What I am Trying to Do**

I am stuck on a bit of code. For a specific gravity form (Form ID#14), I want to change the value of a single-line text field (Field ID#14) within the current entry when the user cancels a Gravity Flow Workflow. I have included the references I used to develop the code, but it still does not update the field. Any ideas on what I am missing?

**Here is the code:**

```
//Resource Page - Gravity Flow Hook for Cancellations: https://docs.gravityflow.io/article/162-gravityflowprecancelworkflow
//Resource Page - GFAPI::update_entry_field: https://docs.gravityforms.com/api-functions/#update-entry-field

add_action( 'gravityflow_pre_cancel_workflow', 'sh_gravityflow_pre_cancel_workflow', 10, 3 );
/**
 * @param array $entry //should be current entry
 * @param array $form //Form ID#14
 * @param Gravity_Flow_Step $step 
 */
function sh_gravityflow_pre_cancel_workflow( $entry, $form, $step ) {
    if ( $form == '14' ) {
        GFAPI::update_entry_field( $entry, 14, 'Flagged' ); //Step ID#14
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the field number in quotes?: GFAPI::update_entry_field( $entry, '14', 'Flagged' );

Comment: Rochelle, thank you for your comment. I have tried putting the field number in quotes and it does not make the code run :-(